# How to find and replace date, on timebased trigger by using ScriptApp Custom function

Tags: replace, google-apps-script, google-docs

I have a Google Document with only one date in the body of the document. I am trying to write a script that updates the date every 24 hours.

The date in the document is currently set to "11/01/2016" as text, 1 day less than today (12/01/2016). I assumed using a `replaceText()` would work.

This is my script at the moment.

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction")
.timeBased()
.atHour(24)
.everyDays(1)
.inTimezone("GMT")

function myFunction() 
{
 var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "dd/MM/yyy"); 
 var doc = DocumentApp.openById("ID of Document");
 doc.replaceText(date-1,date) ;
}
```

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: What result are you seeing vs what you expect to see? How is "custom function" relevant to this question? Tip: Having a `.newTrigger()` call outside of a function is a Bad Idea; it will get invoked every time any function in the script is called.

Answer (score 0):

You can't replace text on document object, you need to get document body. your `date` is a string, you can't get yesterday by `date-1`. refer the date conversion too.

```
function myFunction() 
{
 var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
 var d = new Date();
 var yesterdayDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(d.getTime()-1*(24*3600*1000)), "GMT", "dd/MM/yyy"); 
 var todayDate = Utilities.formatDate(d, "GMT", "dd/MM/yyy"); 
 body.replaceText(yesterdayDate,todayDate) ;
}
```

Comment: Your code addresses the problem that `date-1` is meaningless, because `date` is a string... you should mention that, too.